# Usage redondant de « hommage » ? (1819)

Tags: sens

> [[Source:]](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=%22all%20my%20thanks%22&s=1111311111&sa=&r=3&sr=) To Thomas Jefferson from Marc Antoine Jullien, 21 February 1819
>
> […]
> j’ai l’honneur de vous renouveller, Monsieur, avec tous mes remercimens et avec l’expression de tous mes regrets de ce que vos précédentes lettres ne me sont point parvenues, **l’hommage** de mes **sentimens sincéres d’estime et de respect**,
>
> M. A. Jullien de paris

1. À qui ou quoi est *l’hommage* destiné ?
2. L'usage de **l’hommage**, est-il superflu ici ? Ai-je raison que les *sentiments sincères d’estime et de respect* renouvelés impliquent déjà *l’hommage* ?

Comment: La redondance est une considération *logique*, entrant peu en considération dès lors qu'on est dans l'arbitraire des *valeurs* culturelles et sociales comme ici les "bonnes" manières.

Comment: Just a wild thought, but because of the embarrassment & misunderstanding caused by the lost letters, I think the verb “renouveller” was perhaps used with “hommage” here (instead of just “rendre encore” or “répéter”) & its use makes me think of the “renouvellement de l’hommage” of feudal times when “l'hommage” could be evidenced in many different ways (with pledges of one’s loyalty, troops, money, etc, none of which automatically required sincere & respectful sentiments of esteem). Therefore, detailing the specifics of this renewed homage to T.J. from M.A.J. was not necessarily redundant, imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un complément au sujet de l' « hommage » superflu. C'était non seulement  d'usage, comme on l'a [mentionné](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13551), mais aussi parfaitement indiqué dans ces formules en contexte. Voici quelques exemples supplémentaires :

> [**agréer**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/agreer)
>   A. 2. c) [Dans le style [épistolaire](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genre_%C3%A9pistolaire)<sup>1</sup>, par égard pour le destinataire
>   considéré par convention comme ayant le pouvoir de refuser] Agréez,
>   veuillez agréer + subst. abstr. Formule de politesse employée à la fin
>   d'une lettre :
>   -14. *J'userai aussi de toutes les permissions que vous me donnez, en homme bien convaincu de vos bontés. Agréez, Monsieur le commandeur,
>   l'hommage d'un cœur reconnaissant, et l'assurance du respectueux
>   attachement avec lequel j'ai l'honneur d'être, Monsieur le commandeur,
>   votre très-humble et très-obéissant serviteur*. G. Sénac de Meilhan,
>   [*L'Émigré*](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/34561), 1797, p. 1647.
>
> [**hommage**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hommage)
>   D. − Don, offrande. [...]
>   − [Dans des formules de politesse] Offrir, présenter l'hommage de son profond respect et de sa reconnaissance à qqn. *Daignez agréer ceci comme un hommage de ma reconnaissance* (Ac.). *Recevez, monsieur le Comte, l'hommage bien sincère de mon respectueux attachement, et conservez-moi un peu de part dans votre souvenir* (Sénac de Meilhan, [*L'Émigré*](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/34561), 1797, p. 1897). *Je vous prie, Général, d'avoir la bonté de me répondre et d'accepter l'hommage de ma considération la plus distinguée* (Flaub., *Corresp*.,1863, p. 94). *Veuillez agréer, monsieur le Président, l'hommage de mon respectueux dévouement* (J.O., *Décret rel. organ. état-major arm*., 1890, p. 2234).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* - TLFi ]

Ici on a l'*honneur de renouveler* un hommage. Autrement comment aurait-on réservé au destinataire le pouvoir symbolique de refuser quoi que ce soit avec des sentiments sur lesquels il n'a aucun contrôle, et sans même lui avoir demandé d'agréer ? De plus, que signifierait renouveler des sentiments sinon que de les avoir laissés s'éteindre? En quoi est-ce que 'renouveler des sentiments' serait l'équivalent d'un hommage qui, 
à T. Jefferson, constitue l'occasion d'en témoigner ? La traduction présentée par l'éditeur rend facilement le tout : « [...] *the homage of my sincere respects and regards*. ». De plus, dans la [missive](http://founders.archives.gov/documents/Jefferson/03-02-02-0452) de Monsieur Jefferson de 1810, on a des constructions similaires même en anglais : « *and I pray you to accept my thanks for this mark of your attention* » et « *accept my portion of the acknolegements due to you, with the assurances of my high respect and consideration.* ». Il s'agit ici d'un style dans la correspondance d'une certaine époque, avec ses règles et finalités propres.

---

<sub>1. Pour avoir une idée des conceptions rattachées à ce style *au 19ème*, on peut jeter un coup d’œil au [*Traité de l'art épistolaire à l'usage des maisons d'éducation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=n7dcAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PR3&ots=CaimVFzKub&dq=Trait%C3%A9%20de%20l%E2%80%99Art%20%C3%A9pistolaire%20de%20l%E2%80%99Abb%C3%A9%20J.%20Verniolles&pg=PR3#v=onepage&q=Trait%C3%A9%20de%20l%E2%80%99Art%20%C3%A9pistolaire%20de%20l%E2%80%99Abb%C3%A9%20J.%20Verniolles&f=false) de 1863 de M. l'Abbé J. Verniolles (*ed. Étienne Giraud*). On y mentionne les idéaux de fond : *réflexion*, *prudence*, *variété*, '*à-propos*, et *position personnelle*; puis on expose les qualités visées par le style : *clarté*, *simplicité*, *naturel*, *aisance*, *précision* et *convenance*. Au chapitre troisième - *du cérémonial épistolaire* - l'article sixième porte exclusivement sur la *conclusion des lettres*; certains passages en sont impayables (extraits) : **62**. *L’impertinence est partout une triste chose, mais nulle part elle n'est plus choquante que dans les lettres des jeunes gens à des personnes respectables*.[...] **88**.[...]*Plus une personne est élevée, plus il faut user envers elle d’expressions révérencieuses et polies. Mais pourtant les formules humbles et respectueuses devront plus ou moins diminuer à mesure que s’élèvera la position de la personne qui lui écrit*.[...] **93**. [...] *La considération, en effet, est un sentiment qui n'a de valeur que lorsqu’il vient d’une personne élevée*. [...] *ce ne peut être une chose flatteuse pour un haut fonctionnaire de jouir de la considération d'un inférieur. Disons en passant qu’il est ridicule de vouloir se distinguer en signant d'une manière illisible.* **94**. *En toutes choses, même en matière de politesse, il faut tâcher d’être vrai et sincère. Gardez-vous donc, dans la conclusion d’une lettre, de témoigner à une personne des sentiments qui ne sont pas dans votre cœur*.[...] **95**. [...] *À une dame* : «Veuillez agréer l'hommage de mes sentiments respectueux. » (ou) «...de mon plus sincère et reconnaissant respect.» (ou) «...de mon dévouement respectueux.» **96**.[...] *il vaut toujours mieux pécher par excès de politesse que par le défaut contraire. Offrez donc votre respect ou vos sentiments respectueux même à des personnes qui vous les doivent sous certains rapports. Vous pouvez avoir à traiter avec des gens qui connaissent peu la politesse et qui la pratiquent encore moins. Ce ton de réserve et d’urbanité leur servira de leçon et leur indiquera pour ainsi dire le ton et le style de la réponse. Quand on occupe certaines positions, il est bon de tenir les autres dans des bornes qu’ils ne sont que trop disposés à franchir. Il faut être aimable, poli, complaisant envers tous; mais il faut être pourtant digne et ferme, et éviter une sorte d'obséquiosité qui fait perdre toute dignité*. -// Non sans rappeler les règles d'étiquette de l'époque victorienne; mais, peu importe le style du temps, on aime que ce soit bien senti, et ce peu l'être ou non.</sub>

Comment: +1. Merci. SVP, veuillez désambiguîser: 1. `serait-ce` dans `serait-ce`? Quel est l'antécédent de `ce` ici ?

Comment: 2\. `lui` dans votre phrase : `en quoi serait-ce l'équivalent d'un hommage qui, lui, constitue l'occasion d'en témoigner ?`.

Comment: SVP, pourriez-vous répondre aux questions supplémentaires dans votre réponse propre (et non pas à titre de commentaire) ?

Comment: Je vous en prie. C'est moi qui vous demande de daigner agréer l'hommage de mes remerciements pour votre aide ici et dans mes autres réponses !

Comment: En outre, j'ai légèrement amendé votre réponse pour faire intégrer vos commentaires ci-dessus. Informez-moi si je me trompe.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. À qui ou quoi est l’hommage destiné ?

Marc-Antoine Jullien renouvelle ses salutations à Thomas Jefferson.

> 2. L'usage de l’hommage, est-il superflu ici ?

Il s'agit d'une formule de politesse "toute faite". Elle n'a rien d'exceptionnel pour l'époque, en particulier s'agissant d'un courrier envoyé à un ancien chef d'État.

> Ai-je raison que les sentimens sincéres d’estime et de respect renouvelés déjà impliquent l’hommage ?

Ils l'impliquent probablement mais l'hommage est là pour renforcer la formule.

Answer (score 0):

Un flagorneur ne peut s’empêcher d'être redondant, de dégouliner de mièvre respect, de baver d'éloge, d'utiliser la brosse à reluire pour lustrer l'ego de la personne qu'il sollicite.

Cela a peut-être encore cours dans les milieux diplomatiques, ou pour solliciter un siège à l'Académie française, ... mais personne n'est dupe.

Surtout ne m'envoyez pas une lettre type de ce genre ! Le silence méprisant comme première réponse, et peut-être un "Faites votre boulot et arrêtez de me lécher le c.l (derrière)" en cas d'insistance stupide.